# Activate a virtual environment in Windows Powershell with a command that is equivalent to "source"

Tags: powershell, virtualenv

I need to activate a virtual environment in Windows Powershell. But, [the guide](https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/fluidity-truffle-box) i am using that to proceed my project tells me to use a command like this:

`source venv-slither/bin/activate`

In my project directory, in first, i installed `virtualenv` with:

`pip3 install virtualenv`

After that, I setup a virtual environment in folder `./venv-slither` with:

`source venv-slither/bin/activate`

Problem emerges here. Whenever i run the last command i approaches to this message in Powershell:

```
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:2
+  source venv-slither/bin/activate
+  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I read some guide to eliminate this. They suggest using `.` instead `source`, but by this way the same error occurs. When, my Command is:

`. venv-slither/bin/activate`

The message is:

```
. : The term 'venv-slither/bin/activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ . venv-slither/bin/activate
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv-slither/bin/activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

More over, when i change slashes direct:

`. venv-slither\bin\activate`

This message comes up:

```
. : The module 'venv-slither' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module venv-slither'.
At line:1 char:3
+ . venv-slither\bin\activate
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv-slither\bin\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

I have these modules in my project directory: `.bin, dot, findit, source`.
Please help a beginner man in working with Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like this, within Windows PS:

```
venv-slither/Scripts/activate.ps1
```

After enabling the necessary execution policy for the current user with this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

I would return to previous policy with this command, after you finish your work, for safety:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope CurrentUser
```

There are other ways to set the execution temporarily. For example, I can set for the current PS's session by issuing this command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

* RemoteSigned or Unrestricted, you can refer to this link to view the details which scripts are or not allowed for each type of policy:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1

Sorry for posting too late, I've just run into your post when found the same issue, tested myself and it worked.